# Galaxy S Blank Email When Called

Tags: java, android, forms, email, galaxy

I have created a form app where the user fills out the form then clicks a submit button which formats the user data in an email. The app populates the data in the body of the email on my Droid Charge but when someone uses a Galaxy S the body of the email is blank. Does anyone know of a fix for this problem?

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
                    android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                    new String[] { "email@email.com" });
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                    "Form on " + String.valueOf(editText1.getText()) + "Tech " + String.valueOf(editText2.getText()));
            emailIntent.putExtra(
                    android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    "Completed by = " + String.valueOf(editText1.getText())
                            + " / " + String.valueOf(editText2.getText())
                            + '\n' + "Tech Center = "
                            + String.valueOf(editText3.getText())
                            + '\n' + "Job # = "
                            + String.valueOf(editText4.getText())
                            + '\n' + "Date = "
                            + String.valueOf(editText5.getText())
                            + '\n' + "Address = "
                            + String.valueOf(editText6.getText())
                            + '\n' + "Type = "
                            + String.valueOf(spinner7.getSelectedItem())
                            + '\n' + "Work = "
                            + String.valueOf(spinner8.getSelectedItem())
                            + '\n' + "Location = "
                            + String.valueOf(spinner9.getSelectedItem())

                            //code omitted

                            + '\n' + "Referrals = "
                            + String.valueOf(editText8.getText())
                            + '\n' + String.valueOf(result11.toString()));

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Mail"));
            finish();

        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Update: The user with the Galaxy S selected Gmail instead of Email and it populted in the body of the Gmail app.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Intent.ACTION_SENDTO` action instead. This has the added benefit of having only actual e-mail apps appear in the chooser.

Unfortunately, I don't think that you can use intent extras to fill in the e-mail when using `Intent.ACTION_SENDTO`. You'll have to use something like this:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO).setData(Uri.parse(String.format(
   "mailto:%s?subject=%s&body=%s",
   recipient,
   subject,
   body
).replace(" ", "%20")));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have a Galaxy S to test with. It might be a while before I can test the new code. Thanks for the information.